# CSS Parentheses/Double semi-colon?

Tags: css

how come this makes the width to be 100%?

```
.test {
    width: (50%;);
}
```

I already know how to fix it so it becomes 50% and that the statement is more or less redundant, I'd just like to know why this behavior happens.

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/k57z9/

Comment: Because it's completely invalid and is ignored, and the standard behaviour is 100%...?

Comment: Because it's invalid... And if you set that value on a `div`, it will still be a block level element, at 100% width

Comment: If it is ignored, how does the width become 100%?

Comment: Still interesting though. We know it is invalid, but *why* does it happen?

Comment: Provide a fiddle test-case (and full test-case code here too) for such questions - chances are an important detail is missing.

Comment: What element is the `.test` class asigned to?

Comment: The default for `width` is `auto` so it's not odd it goes to `100%` (block elements anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming `.test` here is a `<div>` or other *block level element*. These elements *by default* have a 100% width (well, `auto` really, which means 100% minus padding). The broken CSS rule is ignored because it's, well, broken. So the element is 100% wide by default. You'd get the exact same result by not writing any CSS at all.